# Ruby : Twitter API V2.0 error 401 Unauthorized (OAuth)

Tags: ruby, api, heroku, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm currently creating a Twitter bot in Ruby. This bot must tweet the result of a web scraping everyday. Everything works perfectly but I have a problem with the API part. I got all of my API keys from Twitter and I can tweet from Postman. I got the request directly from Postman but for some reason, when I try to execute my script in my terminal, I got this message :

```
{
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "type": "about:blank",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I'm currently testing my script from my terminal but it will be executed from heroku with the scheduler in the future.
Do you understand where the problem comes from? I read that I might need to create callbacks URL in Twitter Dashboard but I have no idea what I need to enter as I'm testing my script in the terminal.

Thanks :)

Here's my script (I skipped the scraping part):

```
require "json"
require "net/http"
require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri"

#Tweeting result
url = URI("https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["Authorization"] = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key='#{ENV['CONSUMER_KEY']}',oauth_token='#{ENV['ACCESS_TOKEN']}',oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1',oauth_timestamp='1644297052',oauth_nonce='yxABTHBJyWM',oauth_version='1.0',oauth_signature='pWxeExVF46ueXyblWfz4vzzuRCg%3D'"
request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
request["Cookie"] = "guest_id=v1%3A164429705219615684"
request.body = JSON.dump({
  "text": "Nombre d'adhérents : #{total}"
})

response = https.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

Comment: Did you verified the Authorization header like dumping it to terminal or checking with a debugger?

Comment: @alpert What I'm supposed to check? And how exactly?